# My sprite doesn't show anymore after optimization. Why isn't my sprite showing in my pygame code?

Tags: python, pygame

I encountered the problem by creating the classes and using def for the character
to optimize the code like the video I'm watching. 
reference video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfnRywBv5VM
The code runs but my sprite won't show except for my background. 
I'm not really sure what is wrong so I just posted the whole code.
I'm a newbie to python, pygame, and coding in general so please avoid using deep terminologies.
Thank you!

```
# Initialize Pygame
import pygame
pygame.init()

# Game Window
window = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 480))

# Game Name
pygame.display.set_caption("Block Z-Day")

# Animation
walkLeft = pygame.image.load('Block Z-Day Sprites/1left.png')
walkRight = pygame.image.load('Block Z-Day Sprites/2right.png')
walkDown = pygame.image.load('Block Z-Day Sprites/3down.png')
walkUp = pygame.image.load('Block Z-Day Sprites/4up.png')
stand = pygame.image.load('Block Z-Day Sprites/5stand.png')
bg = pygame.image.load('Block Z-Day Sprites/background.jpg')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


# Variable init (initialization)
class player():
    def __init__(self, x_location, y_location, width, height):
    # Character Starting Location and Size Declaration
        self.x_location = x_location
        self.y_location = y_location
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    # Character Speed Declaration
        self.velocity = 3
    # Declaration for the Main Loop
        self.left = False
        self.right = False
        self.down = False
        self.up = False
    def character(self, window):
        # Character Face
        if self.left:
            window.blit(walkLeft, (self.x_location, self.y_location))
        elif self.right:
            window.blit(walkRight, (self.x_location, self.y_location))
        elif self.down:
            window.blit(walkDown, (self.x_location, self.y_location))
        elif self.up:
            window.blit(walkUp, (self.x_location, self.y_location))
        else:
            window.blit(stand, (self.x_location, self.y_location))

# Character Attributes (void)
def gamewindow():
    # Background
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))
    # Shows the Character (refreshes display)
    pygame.display.update()

# Main Loop
dude = player( 240, 240, 40, 50)
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    # User Inputs
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # Quit Button
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    # Character Movement and Boundaries
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_a] and dude.x_location > 0:
        dude.x_location -= dude.velocity
        dude.left = True
        dude.right = False
        dude.down = False
        dude.up = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_d] and dude.x_location < 480 - dude.width:
        dude.x_location += dude.velocity
        dude.left = False
        dude.right = True
        dude.down = False
        dude.up = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_s] and dude.y_location < 480 - dude.height:
        dude.y_location += dude.velocity
        dude.left = False
        dude.right = False
        dude.down = True
        dude.up = False
    elif keys[pygame.K_w] and dude.y_location > 0:
        dude.y_location -= dude.velocity
        dude.left = False
        dude.right = False
        dude.down = False
        dude.up = True
    else:
        dude.left = False
        dude.right = False
        dude.down = False
        dude.up = False
        dude.stand = True
    gamewindow()
```

Comment: _# Variable init (initialization)
class player():_ What do you mean by _Variable init (initialization)_? That class should be named `Player`, by the way. Since the character can seemingly only move in single direction at a time, why not use a single variable with 4 possible values, instead of 4 variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to draw the player (`dude`) in `gamewindow`:

```py
# Character Attributes (void)
def gamewindow():
    # Background
    window.blit(bg, (0, 0))

    # draw character
    dude.character(window) # <------

    # Shows the Character (refreshes display)
    pygame.display.update()
```